# How to watch a directory permanently in kafka connect

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I create a custom kafka connector to read a directory files and put records on kafka topic. I want to keep watching the directory for new files and poll them to kafka topic. My connector works fine, but when I create a new file in the directory it does not read it. Any suggestions or solutions ?

Thank's

Comment: Have you looked at https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir? This already does it.

Comment: Filebeat, Fluentd, NiFi, and Streamsets can all do this (and write to Kafka)... Don't reinvent the wheel